# User defined function with while loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am asked to create a user defined function in SQL Server to returns the following pattern (for example, if the input = 5):

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Here is my code:

```
alter function udf_star (@input int)
returns varchar (200)
as 
begin 
    declare @star int 
    set @star = @input 

    declare @space int 
    set @space = 0

    while @star > 0
    begin 
        declare @string varchar (200)
        set @string = replicate (' ', @space) + replicate ('*', @star)

        set @star = @star - 1
        set @space = @space + 1  
    end 

    return @string 
end
```

When I execute the function

```
select dbo.udf_star (5)
```

it only shows

```
'    *'
```

(4 spaces + 1 star); can anyone points out how should I correct the syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: . .(1) Use the recursive CTE that I suggested in your previous answer; (2) You seem to want to return a table, not a scalar value.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, yes, CTE is a good solution, but I am trying different SQL tools and wondering how I can achieve this by UDF.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you may want a Table-Valued Function.

Also, loops should be avoided when possible

**Example**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Star] (@Input int)
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

Select Top (@Input) 
       Stars = replicate(' ',@Input-N)+replicate('*',N)
 From ( Select Top (@Input) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) A
 Order By N Desc
)
```

**If you were to :**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Star](5)
```

**The Results**

```
Stars
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```