# Print rows of stars using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replicate the following code in SQL Server to PostgreSQL:

```sql
declare @row int = 1
while (@row < 6)
begin
    print replicate('* ', @row)
    set @row = @row + 1
end;
```

## Required output

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`

```
select rpad('*', i, '*')
from generate_series(1,5) as g(i)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2ddbd44fbd4342719aa49811ac923ca0)

Comment: I just tested in pgAdmin and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A small follow up question, how to print in reverse? i.e. 5stras, 4stars, etc.

Comment: @MilkyWay001: switch the order of `generate_series()`https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=abc14627d52215f439532e20b700c185

Answer (score 2):

Loops should be avoided when possible.   In SQL Server, you can use an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select Top (5) Stars=replicate('*',Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))) 
 From  master..spt_values n1
```

**Returns**

```
Stars
*
**
***
****
*****
```

**EDIT - Descending Order**

```
Select Stars = replicate('*',N)
 From (Select top (5) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values n1 ) A
 Order By N Desc
```

Comment: @MilkyWay001 It really does work in SQL Server.   I was really demonstrating that loops should be avoided.   The SQL Server option would be as above   See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=237efc32e5758903132a460b51cffae9

Comment: Thanks John, it works in sql-server but I was trying to replicate this in postgresql.

Comment: How to print in reverse order like 5 stars, 4stars, etc in ms-server (I guess you prefer ms-server)?

Comment: @MilkyWay001 Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125707/user-defined-function-with-while-loop-in-sql-server/61126170#61126170

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a lot of advanced than I expected. I need to brush up more of my SQL skills.

Comment: @MilkyWay001 See Edit

Comment: @MilkyWay001 That's the FUN part.  I learn something new every day on this site !